# Third order derivative limit form

Tags: calculus

Suppose function $f$ is twice differentiable and $f'''(0)$ exists and show the following:$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{4(f(h)-f(-h)-2(f(\frac{h}{2})-f(-\frac{h}{2})))}{h^3}=f'''(0)$$

**My thoughts** (I really do not have a clue for this one so I just share some of my thoughts.)

$1.$  I am assuming we have to show that $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{4(f(a+h)-f(a-h)-2(f(\frac{a+h}{2})-f(\frac{a-h}{2})))}{h^3}$ $=$ $f'''(a)$ first then substitute in $a=0$.

$2.$ the existence of '$\frac{h}{2}$' makes me think that this uses the formula relating to 'central difference' formula rather than forward or backward.

$3.$ I have also thought about using Taylor's formula as $f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2f''(x)}{2}+\frac{h^3f'''(x)}{6}$ and $f(x-h)=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2f''(x)}{2}-\frac{h^3f'''(x)}{6}$ but I am not sure how to continue that either.

Comment: Just Wandering, try following MathematicianByMistake's good advice below.  Let us know what you come up with.

Comment: @irchans I have thought about this question again, can I use L'Hopital's Rule three times, which will also gives what I need? If not, why cannot this method work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: After the first use of L'Hospital's rule, the numerator and the denominator are still both converging to 0.  After the second use of L'Hospital's rule, the numerator and the denominator are not converging to 0, so you can't use L'Hospital's rule a third time.   Try doing it twice and try typing your progress below your question.  People will help.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***HINT***

$$f'''(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f''(h)-f''(0)}{h}=\lim_{-h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f''(-h)-f''(0)}{-h}$$

Aplly L'Hospital's Rule twice and "break" the large fraction that appears.

You will also have to add/subtract $f''(0)$ in the numerator $2$ times to make $f'''(0)$ appear.

Comment: @irchans Indeed, thanks for the nice catch!

Comment: Hmm, I have got to the step where $\frac{2f''(h)-2f''(-h)-f''(\frac{h}{2})+f''(-\frac{h}{2})}{3h}$ $=$ $\frac{f''(-h)-f''(0)}{-h}$$+$$\frac{3f''(0)-f''(-h)+f''(\frac{h}{2})-f''(\frac{-h}{2})}{-3h}$ and I am not too sure how to handle the other bit

Comment: @JustWandering Bare in mind that $\Large f'''(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f''\Big(\frac{h}{2}\Big)-f''\Big(0\Big)}{\Large{\frac{h}{2}}}$  In the end you get $\Large\frac23 [f'''(0)+f'''(0)]+\frac13f'''(0)=\frac33f'''(0)=f'''(0)$ If that is not enough I will try to provide the full answer tommorow.

Comment: You are a genius! I have got it now, thank you! This was actually a great fun doing this question. (P.S. i think you mean to to put a minus instead of a plus in the comment)

Comment: @JustWandering I am most certainly ***not*** a genius but very happy to help I certainly am!